# Apple Watch to Watch communication

Tags: nfc, apple-watch

is this possible using their NFC? and if so can it be done continuously as a background running app that wont require the user to constantly launch?

I found this solution : [Passing data to Apple Watch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025526/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app)
but wasnt sure if it was just from Watch -> to non-watch Devices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no API to do this, what is more there is no API that expose hardware like Bluetooth, NFC, heart-rate sensors etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the Watches are from different people and hence do not have the same apple id used to sign in to their companion iPhone.  This would preclude a use of hand-off to mediate data transfer.

What you could do is have a web server that holds the data you want to communicate, and use iPhones to get notifications from it.  Then post those to the Apple Watches.