# Make SwiftyUserDefaults array accessible to iOS and watchOS app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, swiftyuserdefaults

I am using the excellent [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults), a wrapper for `NSUserDefaults` with Swift to allow my app to persist a certain array of data, like so (lots of code removed to show just the important parts:

**Working Code**

```
 import SwiftyUserDefaults //The following is to show implementation in the parent iOS app. It works fine.
    class ViewController: UICollectionViewController { 

    var arrayToStore = DefaultsKey<NSArray>("arrayToStore")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         Defaults[arrayToStore] = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3"]
        }
     func aFunctionThatNeedsToReadTheArray() {
         print([Defaults[arrayToStore]])
         }
    }
```

**Research**

The above works fine, but I also want the watchKit watchOS 2 app of this parent app to be able to read arrayToStore.

I did a bit of [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025526/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app) and learned that Apple offers a solution for this, App Groups, which enables things in NSUserDefaults and other data storage means to be available across apps - in this case, between a parent iOS app and its companion watchOS watchKit app. EDIT: I LEARNED THANKS TO @PETAHCHRISTIAN THAT APP GROUPS DOES NOT WORK FOR WATCHOS 2. SO, WHAT OTHER MEANS ARE THERE?

Edit 2: Knowing that App Groups is not the solution, I did a bit more research and have determined that a possible solution is the`WatchConnectivity` framework. Is this correct, and if so, how can I use it to allow the watch app to have access to `arrayToStore`?

**Question**

However, my question is: **How do I do this with `SwiftyUserDefaults`? I want to be able to have `arrayToStore`, an array in the parent app, readable by the watchOS 2 app via app groups (or another means, if there is a better way NOTE: Thanks to @PetahChristian I have learned that App Groups is not the way to do this. As such, how can I obtain the desired result of the watch app reading an array from the parent app via other means?).**

**What I am trying:**

1. Enable app groups by, in "Capabilities" of the iOS app and watchKit app, turning on app groups and selecting the app group as shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025526/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app)
2. In the app extension for the watchKit app, using `print([Defaults[arrayToStore]])`, resulting in "Use of unresolved identifier arrayToStore". The expected result is printing "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3"

Comment: [app groups are not supported in watchOS 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851729/nsuserdefaults-not-working-on-xcode-beta-with-watch-os2).

Comment: @PetahChristian Thanks! If you post an answer of how to do this without app groups, I would be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/)

You can send a request from the watch to the phone and then send something back to the watch. I would store the array in a Singleton, and then use the `sendMessage` function of WatchConnectivity. This function works even if the iPhone App is in Background.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My apologies, I am still learning Swift, and I am not sure I know how to implement what you suggested: if you by any chance could add some code to your answer to show me what you mean, that would be great... And thanks for answering, I have accepted it.

Comment: No problem. I've learned a lot from this turoail: http://www.raywenderlich.com/117329/watchos-2-tutorial-part-4-watch-connectivity  
It's awesome and easy to understand. I would advice you to follow this, because it's basically the same problem you have