# App Groups not working (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-group

I am trying to pass data from my iPhone app to my Apple Watch app. I already have a working today extension widget (not sure if that requires app groups) but I cannot get the Apple Watch to read NSUserDefaults.

**SET**

`let defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mySuite")`

```
defaults.setObject(dates, forKey: "allDates")
```

---

**RETRIEVE**

```
var theDates = defaults.arrayForKey("allDates")
```

---

Nothing is crashing, but the NSUserDefaults call returns nil. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of object is dates? Try objectForKey.

Comment: That does not work..

Answer (score 0):

WatchOS 2 requires a different method of transferring data between the iPhone and the Apple Watch.

See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35022352/5527548)