# iOS WatchKit - Adding Key Value Observer to NSUserDefaults crashes

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, key-value-observing, watchkit

I am trying to add the ability to send data from iPhone to Watch.
I have setup App Groups and everything runs smoothly, but when I try to add an observer to NSUserDefaults in the Watch Extension file, the app always crashes on startup.
(And yes, I have verified that the app group name is correct and checked in all Target Capabilities AND all provisioning profiles are up-to-date with App Group enabled)

Code:

```
override func willActivate() 
{
    super.willActivate()

    NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "my.suite.name")?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "phoneSaysHello", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

override func didDeactivate() 
{
    super.didDeactivate()

    // Remove listener for commands sent from phone
    NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "my.suite.name")?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "phoneSaysHello", context: nil)
}
```

Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance
>   0x7f99534559b0 of class NSUserDefaults was deallocated while key value
>   observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:
>    ( 
>   Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f9953609200> )'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `NSUserDefaults` have gone out scope. Turning `userDefaults` into an instance variable should stop the exception being thrown.

Comment: That was an issue when using the 'if let'. I updated to use the NSUserDefaults reference itself, and still get the same crash/error. See updated code.

Comment: Try keeping the defaults as an instance variable of your class

Comment: Ok changed to instance variable. Doesn't crash, but the observer is never hit when the NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "my.suite.name") is updated by the phone. Does using an instance variable mean that the watch won't recognize when the phone updates it's own instance variable of the app group NSUserDefaults?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of: Observing defaults isn't a valid way of communicating between your app and watch extension. For that, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/27144114/22147 or https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole. However, look on the bright side: your crash is fixed.